# Java Socket need to get name of sender

Tags: java, sockets

I'm starting with Socket Server in Java. I've written already simple app where I can send text between hosts. I'm sending with my message name of the host which is sending and here is my problem, how can I get host message?

Can someone just change my code to show host name instead of message?

Here is the code:

```
public class FMain extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane = null;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FMain frame = new FMain();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public FMain() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 508, 321);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        PReceiver receiver = new PReceiver();
        receiver.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        receiver.setBounds(35, 13, 423, 106);
        contentPane.add(receiver);

        PSender sender = new PSender((String) null, 0);
        sender.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        sender.setBounds(35, 132, 423, 129);
        contentPane.add(sender);
    }
}
```

And the class which is receiving:

```
interface MyListener {
    void messageReceived(String theLine);
}

class Receiver {
    private List < MyListener > ml = new ArrayList < MyListener > ();
    private Thread t = null;
    private int port = 0;
    private ServerSocket s = null;
    private boolean end = false;

    public void stop() {
        t.interrupt();
        try {
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void start() {
        end = false;
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    s = new ServerSocket(port);
                    while (true) {
                        Socket sc = s.accept();
                        InputStream is = sc.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        String theLine = br.readLine();
                        ml.forEach((item) - > item.messageReceived(theLine));
                        sc.close();
                    }
                } catch (SocketException e) {} catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public void addMyListener(MyListener m) {
        ml.add(m);
    }

    public void removeMyListener(MyListener m) {
        ml.remove(m);
    }

    Receiver(int port) {
        this.port = port;

    }

}

public class PReceiver extends JPanel implements MyListener {

    private JTextField txtPort;
    private Receiver r = null;
    private JTextField txtMessage;

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public PReceiver() {

        setLayout(null);

        txtPort = new JTextField();
        txtPort.setBounds(282, 13, 62, 22);
        add(txtPort);
        // txtPort.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblPort = new JLabel("port:");
        lblPort.setBounds(241, 16, 35, 16);
        add(lblPort);

        JToggleButton btnListen = new JToggleButton("Listen");

        btnListen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (btnListen.isSelected()) {
                    r = new Receiver(Integer.parseInt(txtPort.getText()));
                    r.addMyListener(PReceiver.this);
                    r.start();
                } else {
                    r.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        btnListen.setBounds(265, 70, 79, 25);
        add(btnListen);

        JLabel lblMessage = new JLabel("message");
        lblMessage.setBounds(12, 51, 56, 16);
        add(lblMessage);

        txtMessage = new JTextField();
        txtMessage.setBounds(12, 71, 220, 22);
        add(txtMessage);
        //txtMessage.setColumns(10);

    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(String theLine) {
        txtMessage.setText(theLine);

    }
}
```

And the sender class:

```
class Sender {
    public void send(String message, String host, int port) {
        Socket s;
        try {
            s = new Socket(host, port);
            OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out, false);
            pw.println(message);
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public class PSender extends JPanel {
    private JTextField txtMessage;
    private JTextField txtHost;
    private JTextField txtPort;
    private JLabel lblMessage;

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public PSender(String host, int port) {
        setLayout(null);

        txtMessage = new JTextField();
        txtMessage.setBounds(12, 77, 216, 22);
        add(txtMessage);
        //txtMessage.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnSend = new JButton("Send");
        btnSend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    new Sender().send(txtMessage.getText(), txtHost.getText(), Integer.parseInt(txtPort.getText()));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnSend.setBounds(268, 76, 78, 25);
        add(btnSend);

        txtHost = new JTextField();
        txtHost.setBounds(51, 13, 149, 22);
        add(txtHost);
        //txtHost.setColumns(10);

        txtPort = new JTextField();
        txtPort.setBounds(268, 13, 78, 22);
        add(txtPort);
        //txtPort.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblHost = new JLabel("host:");
        lblHost.setBounds(12, 16, 35, 16);
        add(lblHost);

        JLabel lblPort = new JLabel("port:");
        lblPort.setBounds(231, 16, 35, 16);
        add(lblPort);

        lblMessage = new JLabel("message");
        lblMessage.setBounds(12, 58, 56, 16);
        add(lblMessage);

    }
}
```

Comment: so just to understand correctly you can send from client to host but not from host to client? is That correct understood?

Comment: Basically, you're sending `message/nhost`, now personally, I think that's wrong, I'd do it the other way round, but that's me. I'd also (personally) maybe send them as a single `String` or prefix them in some way `message:{message}`; `host:{host}`, as it takes out the guess work.  On your receiving end, you have to do two things, you need to read the `message` and then you need to read the `host`, based on your protocol, this should always occur, so you should have two reads in your read loop

Comment: *'"Can someone just change my code to show host name instead of message?"* - The short answer is no, that's not what SO is for, we can give you some ideas and suggestions on how you might approach your problem, but SO isn't a coding service

Comment: After looking at your code I must agree with @MadProgrammer you just need a bit of tweaking and you are there. Good luck.

Comment: "*Can someone just change my code to show host name instead of message?*" -1, please show some effort.

Comment: You don't need the name of the sender with every message. It is the same for every message from the same socket. Have it sent once, at the beginning of the session.